# How to get archive re-do log file name containing the given SCN in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman

**Scenario:**
Let us consider oracle 3 node RAC. RMAN Managed Recovery is configured between production and standby DBs. Let us assume that the SCNs of 3 nodes are S1, S2, S3 at some point of time respectively. Let Smax=max(S1,S2,S3)

Is there any possibilities to get the archive file name containing the given SCN, Smax in oracle so as to stop applying logs at standby database as soon as the archive logs of the file containing the given SCN, Smax are applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop recovery at a specific SCN, just run recovery until that specific SCN:

```
RMAN> recover database until scn 3087500;
```

If you want the name of the files:

```
RMAN> list archivelog scn between 3087500 and 3087500;

List of Archived Log Copies for database with db_unique_name GUN_O7CA
=====================================================================

Key     Thrd Seq     S Low Time
------- ---- ------- - ---------
2       1    22      A 12-FEB-18
        Name: /fra/GUN_O7CA/archivelog/2018_02_12/o1_mf_1_22_f83lq5l2_.arc

6       2    31      A 12-FEB-18
        Name: /fra/GUN_O7CA/archivelog/2018_02_12/o1_mf_2_31_f83lqm9v_.arc
```